# Which ipk file i have to use to set up the opkg install package at dd wrt fw

Tags: installation, dd-wrt, openwrt, addons, opkg

Check out this tutorial :

https://www.howtogeek.com/98408/how-to-install-additional-software-on-your-router-dd-wrt/ 
or to be more specific, which of this files re the right ones?! 
http://archive.openwrt.org/snapshots/trunk/

How to geek is telling me to use 
http://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/trunk/ar71xx/packages/opkg_618-2_ar71xx.ipk 
 but the file folder "packages" isn`t there anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another link for the opkg install file is here https://canaan.io/downloads/software/icarus/openwrt-ar71xx-generic-trunk-33315/packages/

Comment: Thank you for your help! It should work but the console tells me i have  to use  a ftp or http url, so how to complie the right url ? Or knows someone a diffferent working url?

Comment: download the file to your computer, then use sftp to transfer to the router, then login via ssh to install.

Comment: where can i vote for ? :) you kow so much! What re the common  commands to install the files from hard drive?

Comment: Push the up arrow above the 0 to the left of the answer - The command you need is opkg install 'packagename'